# Lookup of remote interface is not getting recognised in JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, jndi

The following code is used by `IPMBaseBean.class` for accessing remote interface .

```
Object obj = iniCtx.lookup("java:/comp/env/ejb/ODIControllerSessionEJB");
```

In `jboss-web.xml` `jndi-name` is refered as below

```
<ejb-ref-name>ejb/ODIControllerSessionEJB</ejb-ref-name>
<jndi-name>jnp://vwhq5275.whq.ual.com:6200/ODIControllerSessionEJB</jndi-name>
```

Error:

```
Naming exception 
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: comp not bound..
```

Please suggest on this issue.

Comment: are you trying to access an EJB on a remote machine?

Answer (score 0):

While starting JBoss, it shows the Global JNDI names like shown below:

```
 15:26:47,394 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

        hrms/AccountSummarySessionBean/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
        hrms/AccountSummarySessionBean/local-com.cc.hrms.bl.accounts.generalaccount.session.AccountSummarySessionBeanLocal - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

You can then lookup by using that convention

lookup signature - "hrms/AccountSummarySessionBean/local-com.cc.hrms.bl.accounts.generalaccount.session.AccountSummarySessionBeanLocal"

```
initialContext.lookup(ProjectConstants.PROJECT_NAME+className.getSimpleName().substring(0, className.getSimpleName().lastIndexOf("Local")) + "/local-" + className.getName());
```

I am working in JBoss-5 & this convention works fine for me.